# Qt - Some downloaded files have 0 byte

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I'm currently struggling with a Qt app. I'm trying to download some files from Google Drive using QNetworkManager, QNetworkRequest and QNetworkReply.

First of all, my app works fine on a few computers (4 or 5 people tested it and didn't encounter any error). Each file which must be downloaded is effectively downloaded. (About 280 files are downloaded each time this way, and there is no problem.)

The issue is a member of my work team has only 0-byte files. Every single file which is downloaded over SSL doesn't have any content. The only one download on classic HTTP is correctly donwloaded.

Have you ever seen this bug?

All my "download" code comes from this [single tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL).

Edit : After a few tests, we found that the error was `Error creating SSL context ()`.
Thus, we tried to solve it by installing both needed libraries (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll) on the computer but it didn't work. Do you know if it needs some other libraries?

Comment: Your example might be good enough for diagnosing (I don't know - I haven't studied it), but "Complete" means someone can copy/paste it into a C++ file on their computer and compile it. "Verifiable" means that they could then run the program to see the problem.

Comment: Having a real complete example with Qt may be very long - because of all classes and method needed. In fact, what I've posted is a "classic" code and should not (I hope!) have any error. I thought posting a lot of additionnal code wasn't relevant... Nevertheless, should I edit it in order to have a real complete example?

Comment: what is `fileDownloader`? You could show your statement please.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure, I updated my post.

Comment: You could display the `FileDownloader` constructor. :P

Comment: Done! I forgot to say what was m_WebCtrl before pasting this code ^^'

Comment: I think you should know that it is a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we need it to be minimal, but also reproducible, because only by guessing what the author did we get frustrated and/or bored.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. I pasted the link of the tutorial I have worked with. Excepted the fact I used Qt5-connect syntax, that's exactly the code I used.

Comment: Have you tried using the [error](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error-1) signal from QNetworkReply?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, I didn't know that function! So, we now have the error: `Error creating SSL context`. I updated my question.

Comment: what is your compiler?

Comment: Use that signal and print what you provide so you can analyze it better.

Comment: I think you need to add: libssl32

Comment: It didn't solve anything :/

Comment: @eyllanesc In fact, I had to add some libraries, you were right. But they had to be 32-bit libraries even for 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually about missing libraries. I had to add to my folder :

- libeay32.dll
- libssl32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

The point was, even on 64-bit systems, these libraries had to be for 32-bit systems because I compiled my applications for 32-bit systems...

Moreover, msvcr120.dll was needed for some computers.